# Get the same StackTrace as that which appears in Visual Studio's "Call Stack" window

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, callstack, diagnostics

```
var newStackTrace = new StackTrace(true);
```

or the obsolete

```
var newStackTrace = new StackTrace(Thread.CurrentThread, true);
```

give me a StackTrace that is different from that which I see in the "Call Stack" window in Visual Studio Pro. The current thread's ManagedId is the same as that which I have selected in the "Threads" window. For what it's worth I'm running Debug builds with the pdb files present, and the source matches the assembly.

Where is Visual Studio getting its callstack from? What would cause System.Diagnostics.StackTrace to return a different StackTrace for the same thread compared to Visual Studio?

I've read that stack traces are unreliable, but if I could get the same one as VS gets, it'd do for me.

## Update 1:

Stacktrace from VS:

```
>   A.S.dll!A.X.BORD.ActivateDebugger(object sender = Name={System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, A.X.BOVar>}; Type=, A.X.ActivateDebuggerEventArgs args = {A.X.ActivateDebuggerEventArgs}) Line 1865   C#
    A.S.dll!A.X.BOHost.Debug(object o = {System.Docu.File.DFF}, int line = 93) Line 259 C#
    System.Docu.File.DFF.dll!<Unknown function> Line 93 Unknown
    A.N.dll!A.N.WC.PB.LoadImageAsync(System.IO.Stream outputStream = {System.Web.HttpResponseStream}) Line 137  C#
    A.C.dll!A.C.W.GIAB(A.N.JS.JSO args = {A.N.JS.JSO}, A.N.JS.JSO result = {A.N.JS.JSO}) Line 452   C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    A.N.dll!A.N.CM.AIS.Invoke(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}, object target = {A.C.W}, A.N.JS.JSO[] args = {A.N.JS.JSO[2]}) Line 173   C#
    A.C.dll!A.C.W.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext}, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection responseHeader = {System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection}) Line 210 C#
    A.N.dll!A.N.Http.HTTPH.ExecuteHandler(System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext}, string ashx = "<%@ WebHandler Language=\"C#\" Class=\"A.C.W\" %>\r\n", System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection responseHeader = {System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection}) Line 471 C#
    A.N.dll!A.N.Http.HTTPH.ProcessDefaultRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext}, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection responseHeader = {System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection}) Line 165 C#
    A.N.dll!A.N.Http.HTTPH.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext}, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection responseHeader = {System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection}) Line 374    C#
    App_Code.8jnywgrm.dll!HandlerModule.Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender = {System.Web.HttpApplication}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 92  C#
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step)   Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step = {System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep}, ref bool completedSynchronously = false)    Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error)   Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb)  Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr = {System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest}, System.Web.HttpContext context = {System.Web.HttpContext})    Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext = 0x0000022413f56d40, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)    Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Unknown
    [AppDomain Transition]
```

Stacktrace from StackTrace:

```
   at A.X.BORD.ActivateDebugger(Object sender, ActivateDebuggerEventArgs args) in X:\trunk\Source\S.X.BORD.cs:line 1865
   at A.X.BOHost.Debug(Object o, Int32 line) in X:\trunk\Source\S.X.BOHost.cs:line 259
   at System.Docu.File.DFF.LoadImage(Object sender, LoadImageEventArgs args) in SCRIPTFILE:line 24
   at A.N.WC.PB.LoadImageAsync(Stream outputStream) in X:\trunk\Source.N.WC\PB.cs:line 137
   at A.C.W.GIAB(JSObject args, JSObject result) in X:\trunk\Source.C.W.cs:line 452
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at A.N.CM.AIS.Invoke(MethodInfo method, Object target, JSObject[] args) in X:\trunk\Source.N.CM\AIS.cs:line 173
   at A.C.W.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context, NameValueCollection responseHeader) in X:\trunk\Source.C.W.cs:line 210
   at A.N.Http.HTTPH.ExecuteHandler(HttpContext context, String ashx, NameValueCollection responseHeader) in X:\trunk\Source.N.Http\HTTPH.cs:line 471
   at A.N.Http.HTTPH.ProcessDefaultRequest(HttpContext context, NameValueCollection responseHeader) in X:\trunk\Source.N.Http\HTTPH.cs:line 165
   at A.N.Http.HTTPH.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context, NameValueCollection responseHeader) in X:\trunk\Source.N.Http\HTTPH.cs:line 374
   at HandlerModule.Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in X:\trunk\www\WAS\App_Code\HandlerModule.cs:line 92
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

For our big complicated application running on IIS it's very different (different stack frames, line numbers), for the program listed below, only the line number differs:

```
namespace stacktrace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stacktrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true);
        }
    }
}
```

## Update 2

Once the "Managed to Native/Native to Managed Transition" bits are taken into account, and the formatting is ignored (obfuscating the stack helped me here :-)), the stacks are essentially the same except for the 3rd Frame from top; the one that reports "System.Docu.File.DFF". System.Docu.File.DFF.dll is an assembly generated by us from user "pseudocode" via reflection.

I'm happy that StackTrace found the method-name/line and confused that VS didn't... And that's the bit I need help with.

Comment: Can you please include the link to your reference that says that stack traces are unreliable?

Comment: Is it that you're not examining all the frames (i.e. `stacktrace.GetFrames()`). Please show examples of how your stack trace is different than VS. It's also not clear where you're breaking in VS to compare the two from your code sample.

Comment: @RufusL I just read something somewhere by Eric Lippert.

Comment: @RufusL I've attached (obfuscated) stack traces. I'm just breaking on some arbitrary breakpoint.